# Disable toggle function on specific field

Tags: jquery, html, css, input, toggle

From the following code, the content collapse when click on the grey bar and expands if click again. There is a search input field on the grey bar also, but the content collapsed when I click on it.

What I want is **disable the toggle function in input field**, but maintain the rest. Which means when I click on other parts of the grey bar, the toggle is still functioning, except the search input. Is that a way to do it? Hoping that some of you could provide me with some advice. Thanks!

```js
$(".aq_epdtitle").click(function() {
  $('.aq_expandct').slideToggle().toggleClass('active');
  $(this).closest('.mobexpand').toggleClass('collapsed');
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.aq_expandct {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #aadfff;
}

.aq_epdtitle {
  background: #ccc url('https://image.ibb.co/jUyN5Q/arrow_up_grey.png') no-repeat;
  background-position: right 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.collapsed .aq_epdtitle {
  background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/d669kQ/arrow_down_grey.png');
}

.floatleft {
  float: left;
}

.floatright {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="mobexpand collapsed">
    <div class="aq_epdtitle">
      <div class="floatleft bold"><span>Pending Submission</span></div>
      <div class="floatright"><input class="searchapp" name="searchapp" type="text" value="" placeholder="Search application no." alt="Search application no." /></div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="aq_expandct">
      <p>content</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `event.stopPropagation()`.

I've added another click function for the input, and added `e.stopPropagation()`. This stops the event bubbling.

```js
$(".aq_epdtitle").click(function() {
  $('.aq_expandct').slideToggle().toggleClass('active');
  $(this).closest('.mobexpand').toggleClass('collapsed');
});

$(".searchapp").click(function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
ul { list-style-type: none; margin:0; padding: 0; } 

.aq_expandct{
 padding : 5px;
  background-color: #aadfff;
}
 
.aq_epdtitle{
 background:#ccc url('https://image.ibb.co/jUyN5Q/arrow_up_grey.png') no-repeat;
 background-position:right 0px;
 cursor:pointer;
 padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
 
.collapsed .aq_epdtitle{
 background-image:url('https://image.ibb.co/d669kQ/arrow_down_grey.png');
}

.floatleft{float:left;}
.floatright{float:right;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="mobexpand collapsed">
    <div class="aq_epdtitle">
      <div class="floatleft bold"><span>Pending Submission</span></div>
      <div class="floatright"><input class="searchapp" name="searchapp" type="text" value="" placeholder="Search application no." alt="Search application no."/></div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="aq_expandct">
      <p>content</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```